# How to include the image from the relative Directory to a root Directory in php

Tags: php

```
|root 
| subdir 1 
|   subdir 2
|     subdir 3
|       subdir 4
|         subdir 5 
|              myphp.php 

|relativeroot2(images directory)
   img1.jpg
```

In the above myphp.php script Iam trying to include the (img1.jpg)from relativeroot2 dir.Iam not able to do that how can i include it . when i say `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` iam returned with value as "root" from ther how can include it
`<img src ="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>"/relativeroot2/img1.jpg">`

Comment: Is this directory outside of the web root?

Comment: @mikevoermans: yes it is outside of the webroot

Comment: If it's outside the web root it cannot be served. You'll have to get the contents of the file and print it with the appropriate mime-type header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is how your web folder looks

```
 root
  /includes
  /relativeroot1
  /relativeroot2
```

Create a file named `path.php` in the `includes` folder above and insert the following

```
<?php

if (session_id() == '') {
    session_start(); /* if not already done */
}

/* replace value below with appropriate header to root distance of this include file */

$header_to_root_distance = 1;
$header_dir = dirname(__FILE__);

$root_distance = substr_count($header_dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) - $header_to_root_distance;

  if($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']){
     $include_distance = substr_count(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']), "/");
  }else{
     $include_distance = substr_count(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']), "\\");
  }

$r_path = str_repeat('../', $include_distance - $root_distance);
$_SESSION['r_path'] = $r_path;

 /* Note - $r_path holds your relative url starting from the root folder */

?>
```

Create a `.htaccess` file in the `root` folder above and insert the following

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    php_value include_path "includes/"
</IfModule>
```

Now open the file you want a relative path e.g your `myphp.php` script and insert the following at the top

```
<?php require 'path.php' ?>
```

So to request for any relative path from any file in your case. Just do the following

```
  <img src="<?php echo $r_path.'relativeroot2/img.jpg' ?>" title="My Image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If your diagram is showing that relativeroot2 is outside of root, but in the same parent directory, you can just use `../` to go up one level before specifying it. You also have a stray double-quote in your image tag.

```
<img src ="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>/../relativeroot2/img1.jpg">
```

Comment: i would use `dirname(__FILE__)` in PHP 5.2 or when you have php 5.3 there is a constant `__DIR__` which do the same as $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Comment: It looks like `__DIR__` and `dirname(__FILE__)` both return the parent directory of the currently executing file. Is that right? $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] always gives you the web root directory. I use it when I want to specify a path that's not relative to the current file (e.g., to specify the location of include files that are used by many different documents).

Comment: @octern: Iam still not able to access the image with teh code provided by you