# include image file from web root directory into HTML

Tags: php, html

I like to include an image from the web root directory(www). In the HTML I am using the following code:

```
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
```

But the above code is looking for the image from current directory and then images/logo.png
I do not want to include absolute path on my html code. Is there any easy method to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use paths relative to the web root by starting with a slash.

```
<img src="/images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
```

As you've found, starting without a slash is relative to the current document.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="../../../images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
```

try like this. each ".." will used to go parent directory

Comment: That works, but then you constantly have to remember how many levels deep you are in the directory structure every time that you write a path.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="/images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
```

You have to mention in this manner. The reason is when u mention the path without slash like this

```
`<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />`
```

It will consider it as the path from the root. But you are not actually providing the full path. The procedure to start without slash is

```
<img src="c:/wamp/www/{proj name}/images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
```

So better go for the first one by starting with "/"

Answer (score -1):

[How to include the image from the relative Directory to a root Directory in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092932/how-to-include-the-image-from-the-relative-directory-to-a-root-directory-in-php)